# How to have a paragraph that is hidden unless you click on it in HTML(or XHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, confluence

I am writing pages using python in Confluence that is using XHTML, and I want to have a new page contains a paragraph that is hidden or say truncated when people come to that page but it can be seen if people click on it. 
please check the two pictures I attached in order to better illustrate what I want

[image: this is what I am looking for]

[image: The hidden part reveals once people click on it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to achieve this. Assuming you are using an icon to illustrate those 3 dots.

```
<html>

  <style>#hidden_para{display:none;} /* Hide the paragraph*/</style>
  <p>This is a non hidden paragraph</p>
  <img id="icon" src="3dottedicon.png">

  <!-- Add an id attib to the paragraph -->
  <p id="hidden_para">This is a hidden paragraph</p>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#icon").click(function(){
   $(this).hide(); //this keyword refers to the icon itself.
   //Access the element with the ID hidden_para and override the CSS.
   $("#hidden_para").show();
 });
</script>
```

When the above code is executed it first hides the icon and then adds a style attribute to the element with the ID hidden_para as style="display:block;"(this overrides the CSS specified)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey thx for reply. After run this, the image is broken(do i need to replace sth in the <img id> section? and the hidden_paragraph is directly shown as:
This is a hidden paragraph

<script type="text/javascript"> $(&quot;#icon&quot;).click(function(){ $(this).hide(); $(&quot;#hidden_para&quot;).show(); });

any suggestion why it happens?